# Mobile web user profile no longer has reasonable margins

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

The mobile site's user activity tab recently lost its margins and whitespace for the top part of its content (above the Answers section).  The content (e.g., labels, and badges) now appears flush against the left or right side of the browser window. The bullets are also now misaligned.

The remaining content, starting with the Answers section, to the end of the page, appears correctly, with leading and trailing margins, so the issue is only affecting part of the content.

The mobile site had previously been rendering correctly, earlier today.  Force-quitting Safari, erasing the website data (cache), and/or reloading the site has not resolved anything.

This is happening with Safari on iOS 9.2.1 (running on an iPhone 6s)

> [image]

Comment: Everything is mucked up; there is a stay badge by the SE logo too for example.

Comment: This also applies to Chrome on iOS, by the way.

Comment: This also applies to Firefox on Android, too.

Comment: It works in Chrome on Android.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Perfectly? They've fixed 90-95% of the problems as of several hours ago, but there are still 2 or 3 minor issues that aren't quite back to normal.

Comment: @PetahChristian I didn't notice any immediate issues.